# Как правильно удалять данные с 2-х таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы. Product(сам продукт) и images(id,хранится product_id и путь к картинке). Как правильно реализовать удаление продукта и картинки с бд. Сейчас у меня происходит только удаление продукта (через join вроде удалять нельзя).Как правильно это сделать ? Нужно удалять несколькими запросами ?
Можно ли поменять 2 таблицы с MyIsam на InnoDB ? ничего не поломается из-за этого ? что бы можно было воспользоватся каскадным удалением.

Answer (score 4):

Каскадное удаление нужно настроить, к примеру у вас есть таблицы:

Продукты:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Картинки:

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
        REFERENCES products (product_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

И тогда удаляя продукт картинки будут удаляться автоматически.

Можете почитать вот [тут](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) более детальный пример.

Если у вас таблицы созданы в MyISAM то их нужно конвертировать в InnoDB, можно это сделать вот так:

1. Выполняете запрос:

   SET @DATABASE_NAME = 'name_of_your_db';

   SELECT  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ENGINE=InnoDB;') AS sql_statements
   FROM    information_schema.tables AS tb
   WHERE   table_schema = @DATABASE_NAME
   AND     `ENGINE` = 'MyISAM'
   AND     `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
   ORDER BY table_name DESC;
2. Потом вывод этого запроса копируете и выполняете как новый SQL запрос.

Comment: это если тип Inno. а у меня MyISAM, Могу я его поменять на Inno в phpmyadmin ?

Comment: @Andrii да, в ответ добавил запрос

Answer (score 1):

Join только для выборки данных. Нужно будет сделать два запроса, один на удаление из таблицы images (заодно файл удалить) и уже потом удаление из Product.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал 2 запроса и все вышло.